# How to use EXIST and NOT EXIST clause using lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to filter out orders that do not have an event type Delivered and that works fine.

```
List<Order> matchingOrders = xyzContext.Orders.Where(
                    o => o.FacilityId == facility.MasterFacilityId
                   && rxNumberList.Contains(o.RxNumber)
                   && o.OrderEvents.All(oe => oe.EventType.Code != EventTypeCode.Delivered)).ToList();
```

After that I am trying to filter Orders which has Event type "Ordered" and does not have event type "Delivered" and I am not getting expected result.

```
List<Order> matchingOrders = xyzContext.Orders.Where(
                    o => o.FacilityId == facility.MasterFacilityId
                   && rxNumberList.Contains(o.RxNumber)
                   && o.OrderEvents.All(oe => oe.EventType.Code != EventTypeCode.Delivered && oe.EventType.Code == EventTypeCode.Ordered)).ToList();
```

Comment: This code should work as written. Perhaps there is an underlying issue in the way the code values are managed.

Comment: What do you get instead? Furthermore: what is `EventTypeCode`? Is it a bitwise combined enum or does it contain only one single enum-value?

Comment: @HimBromBeere  EventTypeCode is enum containing many event type code and description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out :

```
List<Order> matchingOrders = xyzContext.Orders.Where(
                o => o.FacilityId == facility.MasterFacilityId
               && rxNumberList.Contains(o.RxNumber)
               && o.OrderEvents.All(oe => oe.EventType.Code != EventTypeCode.Delivered)
               &&  o.OrderEvents.Any(oe.EventType.Code == EventTypeCode.Ordered)).ToList();
```